# ios/unity how to open app with attachment

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, share

I have to do "simple-example" code showing "how to share something by iOS". But I never had iOS in my hands... ;/

What I want: open other app with attachment (e.g. mail, pinterest, twitter etc.)

I found how to do that at Android:

```
AndroidJavaClass androidIntentCl = new AndroidJavaClass ("android.content.Intent");
        AndroidJavaObject androidIntentObj = new AndroidJavaObject ("android.content.Intent");
        androidIntentObj.Call<AndroidJavaObject> ("setAction", androidIntentCl.GetStatic<string> ("ACTION_SEND"));
        AndroidJavaClass uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass ("android.net.Uri");
        AndroidJavaObject uriObject = uriClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("parse", "file://" + photoAddress);
        androidIntentObj.Call<AndroidJavaObject> ("putExtra", androidIntentCl.GetStatic<string> ("EXTRA_STREAM"), uriObject);
        androidIntentObj.Call<AndroidJavaObject> ("setType", "image/jpeg");
        AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("currentActivity");
        currentActivity.Call ("startActivity", androidIntentObj);
```

Is any simple way to do something similar at iOS? Any tutorials etc? I will get iOS for testing just when I show simple example. I completely confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way to do that, you will need to implement it for every platform: tweeter, facebook and others by using the sdk provided by them. And the mail cand be implemented by using the ios provided mail class in xcode.

Comment: Okey. Is any SDK for Pinterest for Unity? I just found classical sdk in java and I haven't idea how to import it to Unity.